# Animation commitStyles does not actually set styles

Tags: javascript, css, animation, web-animations

I'm trying to call `commitStyles()` after an animation is complete so that the styles are retained at the end (by adding to the inline styles) in a way that is performant. However, nothing seems to happen from calling commitStyles, the element just returns to its initial styles after the animation.

Why does calling `Animation.commitStyles` not work at the end of an animation?

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  var a = document.getElementById("target").animate([{
    transform: 'translateX(400px)'
  }], 1000);
  a.finished.then(() => a.commitStyles());
});
```

```html
<div id="target">I can move</div>
<button>Move it</button>
```

Comment: It seems to set the style attribute to `transform: none`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `fill` for an animation is `"none"`, which makes an element revert back to its original styles after the animation completes. Calling [`commitStyles`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/commitStyles) at this point has essentially no effect.

Instead, you can use the `"forwards"` fill to keep the styles after the animation. Then, call `commitStyles()` after the animation finishes and immediately [`cancel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/cancel) the animation to ensure that no more resources are consumed by it. Note that setting the `fill` can achieve the effect of persisting styles by itself, but there are several drawbacks; for instance, it is difficult to change any styles on an element set by an animation (not using `commitStyles`) and the browser has to maintain the animation indefinitely.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", evt => {
  document.getElementById("target").animate([{
    transform: 'translateX(400px)'
  }], {
    duration: 1000,
    fill: "forwards"
  }).finished.then(a => {
    a.commitStyles();
    a.cancel();
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="target">I can move</div>
<button>Move it</button>
```

As an aside, you can see that calling `commitStyles` does work **before** the animation finishes (without setting `fill`) since the animation styles are still active at that time.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", evt => {
  const anim = document.getElementById("target").animate([{
    transform: 'translateX(400px)'
  }], 1000);
  // Do NOT use this approach
  setTimeout(() => anim.commitStyles(), 950);
});
```

```html
<div id="target">I can move</div>
<button>Move it</button>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, we hope to fix this in the spec so the fill mode is not necessary in future: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/5394